# Getting all records from data base to a specific month in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

In My Data Base I have this Reservation record

```
App\Reservation {#2632
     id: 1,
     user_id: 7,
     rest_id: 23,
     reservation_date: "2019-08-29",
     from_time: "16:00:00",
     to_time: "00:00:00",
     count_of_people: 15,
     loyalty_points: 100,
     confirme: 2,
     cancle: 0,
     surveySended: 0,
     surveyAnswer: 0,
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
   },
```

in my controller I have this code trying to retrieve all made reservations in this month:

```
public function getRestAdmin(Request $request,$rest_id)
{

$restaurant=Restaurant::find($rest_id);
  $today=\Carbon\Carbon::today();
//reservations made this month
$reservations=$restaurant->reservations()->where('confirme',2)->whereBetween('reservation_date',[$today->startOfMonth(),$today->endOfMonth()])->get();
 }
```

but I am always getting null!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a reservation in the DB for those dates, try letting Carbon do the heavy lifting before the query directly (without first setting to today):

```
$start = new Carbon('first day of this month');
$end = new Carbon('last day of this month');
```

Then just add the variables to the query:

```
whereBetween('reservation_date',[$start, $end]) ...
```

You can also use this method on Carbon as well:

```
$start = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
```

Comment: It worked!! thanks, but why my method didn't though?

Comment: I think because setting to Today is a different format than what it expects when changing to the date at beginning end of month. ALso, it is possible that the Today gets mutated within the query on the first change to start - I've had that problem before

Answer (score 2):

Force the format from `Carbon`

```
$reservations = $restaurant
    ->reservations()
    ->where('confirme',2)
    ->whereBetween('reservation_date',[
        $today->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'),
        $today->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d')
    ])->get();
```

Comment: for me it worked without the ->format('Y-m-d')

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **whereMonth** and similarly **whereYear**

```
$month = 1; // january 
$reservations->whereMonth('created_at', $month)
$year = 2022; 
$reservations->whereYear('created_at', $year)
```